# How to show tabbar with animation when pop? (iPhone X)

Tags: ios

My app's structure is root->UITabBarController->UINavigationViewController

when push to detailViewController and go back, there are different performance between tap back button and swipe back

- Swipe back has a slide animation with tabbar
- Use back button will show tabbar immediately...

  ```
  class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
      }

      @IBAction func toDetail(_ sender: Any) {
          let controller = DetailViewController()
          controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
          navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
      }

  }

  class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
          view.backgroundColor = .red
      }

  }
  ```

The app is created by XCode Tabbed App template

The image below is with "Tap back button"
[image]

The image below is with "Swipe back"
[image]

Comment: How are you popping the view controller? It should be something like `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` (or `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` if using Objective-C).

Comment: Hi @Alejandro Iván, If I use navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) to pop it, it works well.  My question is when I tap the back button in navigationbar, the tabbar will show immediately without animation.

Comment: Okay ken, are you by any chance **not** calling `super.viewDidAppear()` in your overrides? Also `super.viewDidLoad()`, etc. Remember that you have to call the method in `super` if you are overriding it, as these methods define the view controller lifecycle and statuses.

Comment: Yes! It dose all overrides call its super method.

Comment: add the relevant code, I can’t help you just by guessing :)

Comment: @AlejandroIván you should have just asked for that in the beginning :'D

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I know... I just wanted to discard the most common reason (in my experience) of why animations don't work as expected c':

Comment: There is a simplest project.

Comment: The post updated with code now.

Comment: @ken the default back button handles the pop with animation. They both look same to me. Can you elaborate on what you need?

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri I just upated post with a screenshot

Comment: Is this all there is in the code? I have a feeling this has something to do with something you change in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear in the DetailViewController.

Comment: It's indeed all code for these two controllers

Comment: I just ran the project and both of the animations looked the same. Like the second image on iPhone 8 Plus. :/

Comment: Ok the problem is on iPhone X. I see it now.

Comment: Hahaha, many thanks. iPhone 8 Plus works well.... iPhone X bug?